# How to get rid of warning "Operator used tempdb to spill data"

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a number of stored procedures using mostly the same tables and views that have started to run slow.

I looked at the query plan for one of them and it is giving me two warnings. One is "Columns with no statistics" on a view with a clustered index that is queried with a "no expand" hint.

The second warning occurs later on where there is a Sort in the plan: "Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with a spill level of 1..."

With the intention of playing around with the sql, I scripted a "Create" script and used it to create a second stored procedure. I ran the new procedure still containing identical sql and using identical parameters and the time to execute dropped from 33s to 16s.

As far as I can tell, the execution plans look the same, except that I don't get a warning on the sort.

So what should I do here? Should I recompile all my stored procedures? How can I figure out what has gone wrong and prevent it happening again?

This is occurring on my production database on Sql Azure. No such problems on my local Sql Server database

Comment: Can you let us know the memory grant sizes for the spill and no-spill plan? (Check the properties of the SELECT node in the actual execution plan). Also, take a look at the parameter compiled values for that plan.  Are they the same or different?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to sort out this issue?

Comment: @JoeSack is right, it's got to be parameter sniffing issue.

Answer (score -2):

Please create an index with columns used in the SORT operation.

```
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON SortTable INCLUDE(ColumnsUsedInTheSortSeparatedByComma) WITH(MAXDOP = 1)
```

After creating the sort operation should not have the warning, and should not use TempDB.

Comment: The sort operation appears to be triggered by a group command, and the group is done after a piece of recursive sql, so I don't think I can add an index to the column that it recurses on. What I have done is group before the recursion and again afterwards. The first group results then triggers a hash match operation but it reduces the number of rows in the sort triggered by the second group. It's a bit better